# Different behaviors for restricted access of folders in local drive and network shared drive

Tags: windows, permissions, icacls

I have the following file structure on both my local drive and the network shared drive:

```
Parent Folder
  Folder A
   Folder B
   File A
```

So, `Folder A` is a sub-directory of `Parent Folder`, and `Folder B` and `File A` are sub-contents of `Folder A`.

I would want a particular set of users where `Folder A` is visible to them, but prevent them from accessing its contents (`Folder B` and `File A`)

Then, I have the following permissions set on both drives:

```
icacls "Parent Folder"
admin:(F) 
user:(RX)

icacls "Parent Folder/Folder A"
admin:(F)
```

So essentially, `user` does not have access to `Parent Folder/Folder A` at all.

On the local drive, it works as expected (local `user` able to **see** `Folder A` and being unable to access it).

However, on the network shared drive with `user` as the active directory user, when I go into `Parent Folder`, the `user` is **unable to see** `Folder A`.

What is it in the network shared drive that could be causing this behavior?

Comment: Have you mounted "Parent Folder" from network share to a drive letter? AFAIR Windows has an option to hide folders/shares in Explorer the user don't has access to (e.g. useful for a share that contains the home folders of all users).

Comment: @Robert my `Parent Folder` is a sub directory of a network share. (i.e. `A:\Parent Folder`). Also, I do not want to hide `Folder A`. I want the user to see `Folder A` and when he double clicks on it, the user will not be able to access its contents. Is that possible on network shared drives?